# How to make Automl model with Healthcare Entity extraction as base model?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl, named-entity-extraction

I am facing a problem while making a custom model with Automl. I am supplying Automl with JSONL training data with label **DISEASE**.

My service account has the permission **healthcare.nlpservce.analyzeEntities** and also before Start training i am choosing the option to **Enable Healthcare Entity Extraction**.[image]

But still after 4+ hours of training the model detects only the **DISEASE** label.
It is not detecting **Problems, Procedures**, etc

I am following the [steps mentioned in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/automl-healthcare) .

Attached photo of the service account's permission(no utilization analysis)[image: no utilization analysis[?]]

Can anyone please point me in the right direction....

Comment: I see that you have custom-role, have you run [this command](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/automl-healthcare#set_up_permissions) to grant the permission?

Comment: yes i have that permission.